# Some of the globally installed npm packages are not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mern, heroku-cli

I have **npm** installed globally and whenever I run `npm -v` to check its version, it displays it correctly which is currently `7.13.0`.

I also have **heroku-cli** installed globally but whenever I run `heroku --version` it says:

> ```
> C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
> ```

Inside `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\npm` I have heroku and npm both installed **globally** but whenever I run a `heroku` command it fails to run. I am unable to figure out the issue.

*Below I have attached the screenshot of my globally installed packages directory.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your npm's directory path configuration might have some error.
You can modify path by following steps.

1. Open or create a `~/.profile` file and add your npm path

```
export PATH=C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin
```

2. On the command line, update your system variables:

```
source ~/.profile
```

---

Or else, I recommend changing the npm's default directory which is explained on npm official docs.(https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally). I also had similar issue and followed same instructions.

Comment: I have windows system and in the npm docs its written *Note: This section does not apply to Microsoft Windows.*